# Cifs mounted windows share manually refresh

Tags: windows

After a night of messing around to get my Ubuntu in my windows domain with access to shared files I come to you with another problem.

When I for example make a .txt file in the windows server and swap to my Ubuntu client, I have to manualy refresh the mounted folder with <kbd>F5</kbd>. My question:

Is it possible to have the mount folder update in real time without doing it manualy with <kbd>F5</kbd>?